# How do you repair keycloak user page?

Tags: keycloak, saml-2.0

Hi i am trying to install a SAML 2.0 server with keycloak but the user page not work like in the following screen shot

[image]

With this beautifull error

[image]

Someone know how to correct it ??
Thanks EscapeMan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error using Chrome, but using Firefox it's working fine!

Comment: Ok i will try to change my browser